# How to control the css for two instance of Google Maps autocomplete on the same page?

Tags: css, google-maps

I am using the `.pac-container` & `.pac-item` classes to control one instance of my Autocomplete class but if i have two, how can i control that second container with a different style? I tried adding an id to the parent element but it doesn't seem to work?

```
form#rating_form .pac-container{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: More code would be better, if you could put that on a fiddle ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `.pac-container`'s will be appended to the body, using the form within the selector will not match these div's

You may use the `nth-last-child`-selector to apply a different style.
Example for 2 Autocompletes:

```js
function initialize() {
  var pacs = document.getElementsByName('pac-input');
  for (var i = 0; i < pacs.length; ++i) {
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pacs[i]);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
/*#1*/
body>div.pac-container:nth-last-child(2n) {
  background: red;
}

/*#2*/
body>div.pac-container:nth-last-child(2n+1) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<input name="pac-input" />
<br/>
<input name="pac-input" />
<br/>
```

for 3 Autocompletes it would be:

```js
function initialize() {
  var pacs = document.getElementsByName('pac-input');
  for (var i = 0; i < pacs.length; ++i) {
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pacs[i]);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
/*#1*/
body>div.pac-container:nth-last-child(3n) {
  background: red;
}

/*#2*/
body>div.pac-container:nth-last-child(3n+2) {
  background: blue;
}

/*#3*/
body>div.pac-container:nth-last-child(3n+1) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<input name="pac-input" />
<br/>
<input name="pac-input" />
<br/>
<input name="pac-input" />
<br/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As i was working on it i figured out that it was being injected to the body and not within the id element. I was attempting to use `.pac-container:nth-of-type(2)` but this solution works.